# Splitting template class definitions and declarations fails for nested templates

Tags: c++, template-classes

I know what I want, but I don't know how to tell the compiler what I want. I have split declarations and method definitions in .h and .cpp file, but the .cpp file gets included in the header, so all I did was separate declarations and definitions.

header file (avltree.h) - it includes the source file!:

```
template < class KEY_T, class DATA_T >
class CAvlTree {
    public:

        //----------------------------------------

        template < class KEY_T, class DATA_T >
        class CNode;

        typedef CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T> * tNodePtr;

        template < class KEY_T, class DATA_T >
        class CNode {
            public:
                KEY_T       key;
                DATA_T      data;
                CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T > *    left;
                CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T > *    right;
                char        balance;

                CNode() : left(nullptr), right(nullptr), balance(0) {}

                CNode(KEY_T key, DATA_T data) : 
                    key (key), data (data), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), balance(0) {}
            };

        //----------------------------------------

        template < class KEY_T, class DATA_T >
        struct tAvlInfo {
            CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T> * root;
            CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T> * current;
            KEY_T       key;
            bool        isDuplicate;
            bool        branchChanged;
        };

        typedef bool (* tNodeProcessor) (CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T> * nodePtr);

    private:

        tAvlInfo< KEY_T, DATA_T >   m_info;

        //----------------------------------------

    public:

        DATA_T* Find(KEY_T& key);

    private:

        CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T> * AllocNode(void);
};

#include "avltree.cpp"
```

source file (avltree.cpp):

```
template < typename KEY_T, typename DATA_T >
DATA_T* CAvlTree< KEY_T, DATA_T >::Find (KEY_T& key)
E0276   name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
{
   CNode* root;

   for (CNode* node = m_info.root; node; ) {
       if (key < node->key)
           node = node->left;
       else if (key > root->key)
           node = node->right;
       else {
           m_info.current = node;
           return &node->data;
       }
   }
return nullptr;
}


template < typename KEY_T, typename DATA_T >
CNode* CAvlTree< KEY_T, DATA_T >::AllocNode (void)
E0020   identifier "CNode" is undefined
E0864   CAvlTree is not a template
{
    if (m_info.current = new CNode < KEY_T, DATA_T >) {
        m_info.branchChanged = true;
        return m_info.current;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

What the compiler says (VS 2019 community, c++2020 enabled):

```
E0276   name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
E0020   identifier "CNode" is undefined
E0864   CAvlTree is not a template
```

I have no bloody clue how to write this down the correct way. Please enlighten me.

I have similar code for a template class with a single typename which works, but cannot conclude from that how to do this for two typenames.

Using the tNodePtr type instead of CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T > * in my source code also doesn't work.

Btw, I know that the compiler doesn't "transfer" KEY_T and DATA_T from the CAvlTree declaration just because I am using the same names.

Comment: `source file (avltree.cpp):` for template is suspicious, see [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: [Tangent] You really shouldn't call your template definition file a cpp file.  cpp files are ment to be compiled, and yours isn't.  I'd call it a tpp or ipp file to distinguish that.

Comment: just a suggestion - don't call the implementation file *.cpp - IDEs/build systems will try and compile them - it call it *.imp or *.inl or something similar.

Comment: How should the compiler know what template arguments to choose for `CNode` (at `CNode* root;` and other places in the function definitions)? What do you expect that `KEY_T` and `DATA_T` of `template < class KEY_T, class DATA_T > class CNode;` should be?

Comment: While I agree that using `.cpp` for the file name of the template definitions is a bad idea, the problem the compiler complains about is not related to the current duplicate.

Comment: @t.niese I agree as well and have reopened the Q.

Comment: What you have is a header file that includes another header file. The second header file has a `.cpp` suffix but the suffix is irrelevant. It is only mildly confusing. There is a convention to give files with template implementations a different suffix, often `.inc`.

Comment: @Jarod: The cpp file gets included in the header file. I just split declarations and definitions. I stated this very clearly in my question.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff naming it `.cpp` is still suspicious and can be problematic depending on the toolchain you use. See other comments.

Comment: It works for another class I wrote (linked list class). I built this class after that example, but it just blows up on me ... I also know that just by naming every typename KEY_T and DATA_T doesn't mean the compiler simply matches them. It does when I e.g. pass them to tAvlInfo < KEY_T, DATA_T > which in turn does CNode< _K, _D > * root; I renamed a few things to make clearer that I am aware of that, and also used CNode< _K, _T > * in the included file (which I renamed to avltree.inc, with the result of having no syntax highlighting in my editor anymore. Yay.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the:

```
template < class KEY_T, class DATA_T >
class CNode;
```

Those `KEY_T` and `DATA_T` are unrelated to the one of `CAvlTree`.

clang and gcc even emit an error for those because of name shadowing (I don't know if VS does that too).

Due to `CNode` being a class template, the compiler expects you to provide template arguments for it (like you did for  `CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T> * AllocNode(void);`) at all places where you use `CNode`.

But if you use `KEY_T` and `DATA_T` of `CAvlTree` for every `CNode`  in your code, then the question is why did you define `CNode` as a class template in the first place.

And this part of the code indicates that you don't want `CNode` to be a class template:

```
template < class KEY_T, class DATA_T >
class CNode;

typedef CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T> * tNodePtr;

// …
CNode< KEY_T, DATA_T> * AllocNode(void);
```

The same seems to be true for `template < class KEY_T, class DATA_T > struct tAvlInfo`.

Due to that, I would assume that the code you want to have should look like this:

```
template <class KEY_T, class DATA_T>
class CAvlTree {
public:
  //----------------------------------------
  class CNode {
  public:
    KEY_T key;
    DATA_T data;
    CNode *left;
    CNode *right;
    char balance;

    CNode() : left(nullptr), right(nullptr), balance(0) {}

    CNode(KEY_T key, DATA_T data)
        : key(key), data(data), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), balance(0) {}
  };

  //----------------------------------------

  struct tAvlInfo {
    CNode *root;
    CNode *current;
    KEY_T key;
    bool isDuplicate;
    bool branchChanged;
  };

  typedef bool (*tNodeProcessor)(CNode *nodePtr);

private:
  tAvlInfo m_info;

  //----------------------------------------

public:
  DATA_T *Find(KEY_T &key);

private:
  CNode *AllocNode(void);
};

template <typename KEY_T, typename DATA_T>
DATA_T *CAvlTree<KEY_T, DATA_T>::Find(KEY_T &key) {
  CNode *root;

  for (CNode *node = m_info.root; node;) {
    if (key < node->key)
      node = node->left;
    else if (key > root->key)
      node = node->right;
    else {
      m_info.current = node;
      return &node->data;
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}

template <typename KEY_T, typename DATA_T>
auto CAvlTree<KEY_T, DATA_T>::AllocNode(void) -> CNode * {
  if (m_info.current = new CNode) {
    m_info.branchChanged = true;
    return m_info.current;
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

And using the `auto identifier ( argument-declarations... ) -> return_type` syntax allows you to use the `CName` name directly. Otherwise, you would need to write `template <typename KEY_T, typename DATA_T> typename CAvlTree<KEY_T, DATA_T>::CNode* CAvlTree<KEY_T, DATA_T>::AllocNode(void)`

Comment: Man, I didn't think of not having to make CNode a template class to use KEY_T and DATA_T inside of it ... very good hint! As I look at it I cannot help it but facepalm to myself ... :D I was obviously making things more complicated than I had to.

Comment: There are still some problems I cannot detect the cause of. Would you mind taking another look at my (edited) question?

Comment: @Razzupaltuff don't edit the original question in such a way. Changing the code that way results in a completely different question, and will result in the existing answers not match the question anymore. If you have a new question, then create a new one. You could refer to this question in the new one if you think that this is helpful for the readers.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff regarding what you have asked in that edit, check the last paragraph in my answer. That is the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured it myself pretty quickly. Thanks for the help. :)